# Problem with gcc/g++ versions

Tags: raspbian, c++, gcc

I'm currently setting up [Homebridge](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge) to run on my Pi using [this](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge/wiki/Running-HomeBridge-on-a-Raspberry-Pi#running-homebridge-on-boot-using-pm2) installation guide.

I have run into a problem regarding the [C++ compiler section](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge/wiki/Running-HomeBridge-on-a-Raspberry-Pi#install-c14-skip-this-part-if-you-are-on-raspbian-jessie); I understand that this part of the guide is out of date as the versions in the instructions to not match the [linked guide](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/01/13/raspberry-pi-raspbian-install-gcc-compile-cpp-14-programs/). However, whilst I have successfully followed the other guide and can now execute `gcc-8.1.0 --version` to receive:

```
gcc-8.1.0 (GCC) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

When I run either `g++ -v` or `gcc -v` I receive the following:

```
...
gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1)
```

This is contrary to the main guide which dictates that both `g++ -v` and `gcc -v` should yield the same version as the one installed first (version `8.1.0` not `6.3.0`).

Whilst the main guide does indicate that this may be the case by stating that:

> Now you have the needed compiler, but it is not yet set to be the *default* compiler. You can fix that using the instructions here.
>
> In my case I simply did this:
>
> `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9`
>
> `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 40 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.7`

This does not help considering the versions do not match.

My question is: Do I need to change both the default `g++` and `gcc` versions considering that `g++` and `gcc` already seem to be preinstalled? If so, what command(s) do I need to issue to do this?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Kind regards, Rocco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the main guide says

> Now you have the needed compiler, but it is not yet set to be the default compiler. You can fix that using [the instructions here](https://lektiondestages.art.blog/2013/05/23/installing-and-switching-gcc-g-versions-in-debian/).

If you read the link, it says that after you let your system know that there is an other gcc compiler version

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8.1.0
```

Then you can use the commands

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

to select the default compilers

---

**EDIT**

Let me explain you a little what is going on so that you can understand your problem.

When you try to run a command like `gcc --version` your system searches the paths inside the environment `PATH` variable (windows has one too) to find that program. That variable has the path `/usr/bin` inside it, so it checks if there is a programmed called `gcc` on `/usr/bin/gcc`. You can see your path variable by running `echo $PATH`.

Since gcc comes in many versions, the `/usr/bin/gcc` file is not the actual binary, it is a symlink (something like the shortcuts on the Windows OS) that points to the actual binary (for example `/usr/bin/gcc` points to `/usr/bin/gcc-6.3.0`. You can create a symlink by running `ln -sf /path/to/file /path/to/symlink` (similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux))

In your system the `gcc-6.3.0` is installed as the default compiler. This means that the first gcc programmed found on the paths of `PATH` points to the gcc-6.3.0 binary.

Since you want when you call the gcc the `gcc-8.1.0`'s binary to be called, what you have to do is make sure that the first gcc binary found on the paths of `PATH` is the `gcc-8.1.0`'s binary.

In my raspberry pi the path variable is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` thus the `/usr/local/bin` folder will be checked every time before the `/usr/bin` (your's would be the same).

So what you will have to do is create a the `/usr/local/bin/gcc` symlink.
You can do that be running `ln -s /usr/local/gcc-8.1.0 /usr/local/bin/gcc`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had seen that link but I was unaware of how exactly I would adapt those commands to work with the 8.1.0 version

Comment: Sorry to bother you, just tried out the first command and got the following error `update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0 doesn't exist`. I have a feeling this is because the guide installs it to `/usr/local` rather than `/usr/bin`. How exactly would I need to edit the first command? Or should I simply move where the installation installs the package? Thanks!

Comment: Check my edited answer so that you can understand your problem. If you have questions maybe I can answer them.